# How do I find the generator $(g)$ that generates $(29, \sqrt{-5} ± 13)$

Tags: ring-theory, ideals, integral-domain

> Find the generator $(g)$ that generates $(29, \sqrt{-5} + 13)$. The ring is $\mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{-5}\right]$.

The fact I used was that $\text{Norm}(g)$ must divide both 29 and $\text{Norm}(\sqrt{5} + 13)$, which means solving the Pell equation $x^2 + 5y^2 = 29$. The solutions to this Pell equation are $(\pm 3, \pm 2)$. I don't know what to do with the $\pm$ signs so let's just refer to $(3, 2)$ for simplicity.

Because ideals are subsets, proving ideal equality is proving two subset inclusions.

> Show that $(29, \sqrt{-5} + 13) \subseteq (3 + 2\sqrt{-5})$ and that $(3 + 2\sqrt{-5}) \subseteq (29, \sqrt{-5} ± 13)$. (Because I do not know what to do with the signage, this may not be true.

How do I continue?

Comment: It has been a long time since I've worked with ideals, but they do still need to be ideals over a ring, right? Would it be $\mathbb{C}, \mathbb{R}(\sqrt{-5}), \mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{-5})$?

Comment: Note:  $29=(3+2\sqrt5)(3-2\sqrt5)$

Comment: @InterstellarProbe:  ideals in a field are trivial, so probably $\mathbb Z\sqrt{-5}$ is intended

Comment: Could you please show how to interpret the $\pm$ signs?

Comment: @lhf I significantly expanded the question to include the context of the ± signs. I hope this tells you how to interpret the ± signs. Please help me.

Comment: Does $(29, \sqrt{-5} ± 13)$ mean $(29, \sqrt{-5} +13, \sqrt{-5} - 13)$ ?

Comment: @lhf no. $(29, \sqrt{-5} \pm 13)$ is shorthand for referring to the ideals $(29, \sqrt{-5} + 13)$ and $(29, \sqrt{-5} - 13)$. Both of these ideals are presupposed to be generated by the same element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that $(29, 13+\sqrt{-5}) \subseteq (g)$ we have to find integers $x,y,z,t$ such that $g(x + y\sqrt{-5})=29$ and $g(z + t\sqrt{-5})=13+\sqrt{-5}$.

If $g=3 + 2\sqrt{-5}$ then

$\cases{3z-10t=13\\ 
2z+3t=1}.$

That is $z=\tfrac{49}{29}$ and $t=-\tfrac {23}{29}$, which is impossible.

Let's try $g=3 - 2\sqrt{-5}$ (the other sign choices are reduced to considered by multiplication of $g$ by $-1$). Then

$\cases{3x+10y=29\\ 
-2x+3y=0}$

$\cases{3z+10t=13\\ 
-2z+3t=1}$

That is $x=3$, $y=2$, $z=1$, and $t=1$.

To show that $(3 - 2\sqrt{-5}) \subseteq (29, 13+\sqrt{-5})$ we have to find integers $x,y,z,t$ such that $$(x + y\sqrt{-5})29+(13+\sqrt{-5})(z + t\sqrt{-5})=3-2\sqrt{-5}.$$ That is

$\cases{29x+13z-5t=3\\ 
29y+z+13t=-2}$

$-13z=29x-5t-3=13(29y+13t+2).$

If $y=0$ then $29(x-1)=174t$ that is $x-1=6t$. Thus we can put $x=1$, $y=0$, $z=-2$, and $t=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\,\begin{align} v &= \mp 13\pm\sqrt{-5}\\ w &= \pm3 \pm 2\sqrt{-5}\end{align}\  $ so $\,\begin{align}ww' =29\in (w)\\ \Rightarrow\,(w) = (29,w)\end{align}\,$  so it's the same as $\, (29,w) = (29,v),\,$  true by

$\,v\,$ & $\,w\,$ are associates $\!\bmod 29$, i.e. $\,v\mid w\mid v\ $ by $\ 2v \equiv \mp 26\pm 2\sqrt{-5}\equiv w\, \underset{\large \times\ 15}\Longrightarrow\, v\equiv 15w $